# Promise Returning Undefined When Setting State But Printing to Console Fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm quite new to web dev but I'm trying to build my first front-end app that simply fetches some data from an API and displays it. When I `console.log()` my promise, it returns an array of objects, which is what I want and what I expect from the promise. But, when I try to set my component's state to that same promised array, React is throwing this error:

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Here is the relevant code:

```
const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2020/drivers.json',
    headers: {}
};

export default class DriverList extends Component {

    state = {
        drivers: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios(config)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers)
                this.setState({
                    drivers: res.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers // *** Error pointing to this ***
                });
                console.log(this.drivers)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.drivers.map(driver =>
                    <Driver
                        firstName={driver.giveName}
                        lastName={driver.familyName}
                        driverID={driver.driverId}
                    />)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciate!

Comment: Can you please add "res.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers" here? Is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's not actual data, but `Promise`.

How about trying this??

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getDrivers();
}

getDrivers = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios(config);
    const drivers = res.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers;
    this.setState({
      drivers
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }  
};
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I think there was also an issue in another file that was leading to React throwing the error, so I'm not sure why it wasn't pointing to that code as part of the problem, but either way, it's fixed.